# How to use node packages in NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

How we can use a node package in NestJS? I'm working on a NestJS project and I'm using microservices. I want to use a NodeJS circuit breaker called [opossum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/opossum).
First is it possible to use a node package in NestJS?
If the answer is yes, how can I use a node package in NestJS?

Comment: think like this: `@nestjs/core` is just another nodejs package

Answer (score 2):

NestJS does not replace NodeJS. It's not a new runtime, it's just a framework that uses NodeJS and Typescript. Any package that's valid in Node **is** valid in Nest. Looks like `import * as CircuitBreaker from 'opossum'` should work. If not try `import { CircuitBreaker } from 'opossum'`